# linq distinct query?

Tags: linq

I need a little  help with Linq i have a DB table with restourants tables in it. In the DB i have "TableNumber, Floor , RestaurantID" I would like to get list of all floors. For example if i have this list:

```
TableNumber, Floor , RestaurantID
10             1          1  
11             1          1     
12             2          1     
13             2          1     
14             3          1
```

I would like to get only "1,2,3".

Right now the method returns all rows.

```
        public IEnumerable<ListPad.Item> GetFloorsListPads(SSF.ART.Key restaurant_id)
    {
        return from restaurant_floor in EnterpriseTouchRestaurantApplication.TouchRestaurant.AllRestaurantTables
                where restaurant_floor.RestaurantID == restaurant_id && restaurant_floor.Active == true
                orderby restaurant_floor.Floor
                select new ListPad.Item()
                {
                    Color = Color.SkyBlue,
                    Text = string.Format("{0}", restaurant_floor.Floor),
                    Tag = restaurant_floor
                };
    }
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need either one or two things, depending of whether or not `ListPad.Item` defines equality (by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`) in the way you describe.  If so, then adding `.Distinct()` to your query will give you the distinct items.  If not,  you can do it one of three ways.

1. Return an anonymous type, call `Distinct` on it, and map to the actual type (lazy way)
2. Implement `IEquatable` on `ListPad.Item`, overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (you'll need to research how to properly implement `GetHashCode` so it matches your equality conditions)
3. Define an `IEqualityComparer<ListPad.Item>` that defines your equality.

1 is the lazy way but is less coding.  2 is handy if your conditions define equality for ALL uses of `ListPad.Item` (not just this particular scenario).  3 separates the equality check from the actual type, which is handy if you have *other* cases where equality would be defined differently.